# Definitive location for chromium buildbot's perf plotting javascript code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plot, buildbot

Chromium's buildbot has nice [performance plots](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/perf/xp-release/sizes/report.html?history=50&header=chrome.dll&graph=chrome.dll&rev=-1). To track some metric over time across many versions of your software. It's using a script called [plotter.js](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/perf/xp-release/sizes/js/plotter.js).

I want to use this on our internal buildbot. However I can't find a definitive source for this script. If I grab a copy I want to be able to monitor for improvements or bug fixes, like if someone updates the script.

I got the entire [chromium source](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) and the entire [chromium buildbot source](http://www.chromium.org/developers/testing/chromium-build-infrastructure/getting-the-buildbot-source) and cannot locate this version of plotter.js.  I did find one plotter.js here:
src\chrome\test\functional\perf\endure_graphs\js
but it is entirely different from the one on the web page above.

Any ideas where is the authoritative version of this nifty little script?